# How to fill up a GridView with foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have this GridView markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width ="300px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="TEXT" HeaderText="TEXT" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I want to fill up Gridview with some strings through foreach loop:

```
          foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string f = "this is looping";
            row.Cells[0].Text += f;

        }
```

The problem is GridView1 doesn`t display anything...

Comment: GridView does not filled in loop. GridView's data is bind with List<T> or DataTable. What you can do is performing a loop to fill data into List<T> or DataTable, then bind it with your GridView.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can say have a gv like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="20%">

        </asp:GridView>
```

And then code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        List<string> MyList = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
        GridView1.DataSource = MyList;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```

And we get this:

[image]

Or, we can add a listitem (often used for a drop down list, or say listbox).

Thus:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" 
            Width="20%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="My header"
                    DataField="Text"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

(note how we turned off autogen colums)

code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        List<ListItem> MyList = new List<ListItem>();

        MyList.Add(new ListItem("One"));
        MyList.Add(new ListItem("Two"));
        MyList.Add(new ListItem("Three"));

        GridView1.DataSource = MyList;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So, you can use a simple string list, or even a list item. You loop adding to the object, and THEN feed to the gv.

so, you can loop and build up something, but that thing is THEN bound to the gv.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use foreach loop becouse your GridView doesn't have data source.
Set ObservableCollection as Source, and Add data to collection.

Comment: I added data source and it shows the data but now I tried adding some new data to it but it does not work at all: for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)

            {

                if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.Contains("decreases")) { GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = Label10.Text; }
            
            {      How I understand Cells[0] shows my data and I want to add some new data into Cells[1]

Comment: Like in Albert D. Kallal answer, you need add data to collection setted as datasource of GridView.